# Postgresql Procedure get return schema

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a way to get the return schema of a procedure in Postgresql.  So for example, if the procedure returns a select from a table, it would be that particular result.  So similar to the information schema to see the table columns, I need to see the columns returned in a procedure.

Answer (score 2):

That information is in the `proallargtypes` and `proargmodes` columns of the [`pg_proc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) catalog table.

The output parameters (which are the result columns) will have an `o` or `b` in `proargmodes`.

If it is a function that is *not* declared with output parameters, then the result type is found in the `prorettype` column. If that is a composite type, its columns will be found in `pg_attribute`.